# adding newline in front of Subscript in R

Tags: r

I want to the following text to appear on a heatmap.3 key "value": (\n to allow start on second line) Log2 Fold Change

Using the following code, I got this: Log[2] Fold Change:

```
paste0("\n", expression(Log[2])," Fold Change")
```

The newline worked and the text started started on the second line as required. But, how can I get rid of the []

Comment: Maybe just `"\nLog2 Fold Change"`? Unless you want `2` to be an index.

Comment: what is your expected output? also a reproducible example would help.

Comment: Thanks @Marta. I actually want 2 to be a subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expression` part should be before `paste`; like here:

```
expression(paste("\n", Log[2], " Fold Change")) -> text

plot(1:10, xlab=text)
```

[image]